# How to access weather data from all the stations in one country using openweathermap?

Tags: openweathermap, alteryx

I am using Alteryx to extract weather data for a handful of cities and it works great. I'd like to expand this to able to download data for all weather stations in the UK. At the moment I am specifying which cities I want, e.g. London / Manchester.

Is there a way of specifying in the api call to download all stations in 'GB' or 'UK'?

Ideally I'd like to do this in one call rather than listing all locations which will be very laborious

Comment: You might consider posing this one at http://community.alteryx.com

Answer (score 1):

Get a list of stations or cities that you want to retrieve weather data from.  I found some good sources from openweather here:  http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/

Then build a url request using the list of id's above that retrieves specific weather information.  Using an id for the weather station in Cairns, id=2172797, the url ends up looking like:
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=843798874aac0ef138e6f77c72f3af80

Note that this url will return an error because this isn't a real appid.  If you replace the appid with your own, this url will give you data for that station.

Putting this process into Alteryx lets you put the list of station id's together with the url and the appid to make many calls into openweather and then process all of the data together. I could not find information from the API on rate limits, so be conscious of how many requests you are posting to the service.

There is an example of this process here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yoppbx3bw0p4rug/Get%20individual%20stations.yxzp?dl=0

Keep in mind that you have to update the Appid in the text input tool within this sample as well.